# Separate Tabs into Separate Workbooks, but keep the locked formatting of cells

Tags: excel

Anyone know how to break out the tabs into separate workbooks BUT keep the locked cells locked like in the original file??

This is MULTIPLE tabs... I usually use Kutools to breakout 65 tabs or so into individual workbooks, but I need say the top cells to remain protected. Idk if this is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the sheet name:

[image]

Select Move or Copy. Then select to new book in the second pop-up:

[image]

This will keep all formatting in place.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned multiple tabs not one, thats for the answer though

Comment: You can still use the concept, just rather than selecting `new book` select the book you have created previously.

Comment: Hey VBA Pete, thanks but I figured out what I need within Kutools. Thanks.